# simulate gold foil sticker on glass

Tags: texturing, materials, glass

wise Blender-World folks,

I'd like to do a proper simulation of gold foil stickers on glasses (like a decorated long-drink glass).

I am pretty sure about pictures with transparency and stuff that works well on other materials, but blender's glass-material seems to have a mind of its own...

Anyone around who has some hints?
That would be awfully nice, thank you so much in advance!

Pls have a nice day.
[image]

Answer (score 6):

The setup is quite simple.
UV unwrap your object and use the texture's alpha channel to determine the mix between a glossy shader and the glass shader.

[image]

(click on the image to enlarge)

If your texture image is black and white but does not have an alpha channel then use the color to determine the mix between the two shaders:

[image]