# How to mix glass, glossy and diffuse (sticker on glass jar)

Tags: texturing, shaders, glass

I trying to make sticker on the transparent bottle - but i couldt figure out - how to mix shaders by mask? I place the sticker with help of UV. I can make the bottle completely glass like - or non glass but with sticker.

[image]

[image]

Comment: read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/99266/transparent-image-like-a-decal-on-mesh-with-principled-bsdf-shader/104376#104376

Comment: Also never use the output of a shader as a factor for a mix shader

Comment: Read also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/88382/simulate-gold-foil-sticker-on-glass/88384#88384 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material/46447#46447

Comment: and https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8706/2217

Answer (score 1):

Ok, sure. Before posting this question a play a lot with my file, and was very close to solution - but every time something was not perfect :) In some cases i receive good combination, but some part of sticker was transparent and as inside glass. Anyway i was not quite sure - of what is wrong. After you reply - i found issue with my sticker - it was not exported as i expecting. I attach the difference. For the below right version - i add white non transparent background. So i can control this transparency :)

[image: Difference in alfa channel]
[image: Nodes for material - glass and sticker]
Then i adjust materials and nodes as read it in links - i catch idea in right way.

[image: Here is corrected scene]