# Issues and troubles with a gold decal or gold foil sticker on a glass in Blender 2.8 upwards

Tags: texturing, uv, node-editor

I ran an old problem here (see an [old post of mine](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/88382/simulate-gold-foil-sticker-on-glass) dated back to 2017) - I recently switched from Blender Version 2.79b to 2.8 respectively 2.9...

When modelling some glass now for a new gold decal/foil sticker design, my render (Cycles) came out the way as shown below! Superstrange with a ghost picture. The glass is supposed to only show the decal to a restricted area (like the complete frog you can see...).

This is like what I want to build:

[image: A Glass with Gold Foil Decal]

Oh, of course, I UV-unwrapped the section I wanted to put the decal on - I did it a lot successfully in Blender 2.79b, you know...:

[image: The grid section I marked and UV unwrapped for the Frog/Decal]

But this is the Render outcome:

[image: Render with a strange "ghost frog"...!]

And this is the node setup I built and used:

[image: Node Setup for Decal, like I transferred it from Blender 2.79b]

And here's the "Frog Mask" I intended to use for the gold foil material - Black and Transparency:

[image: Frog/Motive: Black silhouette with transparency]

The glass should be clear except for the centered complete frog design.
Oh - The Frog of course is not yet of a gold material - I just wanted to get the setup right first... But like 6 hrs up until now made no change...

Comment: The issue is not with the materials, but with how the UV maps are created. Please show an image that shows the whole UV map (in the UV map editor) to get better help. Basically you have a UV map that uses not only the area you chose for the frog, but other faces of the object as well. You can fix that by creating a new UV map just for the placement of the frog, or correcting the original one. The node setup  for the material is the same as the one for your original question from 2017.

Comment: Agree with susu...